# Is it bad to declare ng-app and ng-controller on html tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it bad practice to declare both `ng-app` and `ng-controller` on the `<html>` tag?

For example: `<html class="no-js" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">`

Is this considered bad practice? I am trying to control the `<title>` tag of my application dynamically, so I want to declare the `MainCtrl` controller early as it's scope is important in the rest of the application.

Then I can use `<title>{{settings.title}}</title>` in the `MainCtrl` controller and have child controllers access it via `$scope.$parent.settings.title = "hello world";`

Comment: Well...they do that in this blog post: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2450-Using-ngController-With-ngRepeat-In-AngularJS.htm -- Doesn't mention practice tho, just thought I'd share. Good question, +1

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with it. You would just have to take into consideration that now you're defining a pseudo-global controller.

Comment: document.title = "Title"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to access and set the title via the `$window` abstraction, thus removing the need to put a controller on the `html` tag.

Comment: Where would you manipulate the title using `$window`, when it's considered bad practice to do any DOM manipulation in a controller, or anywhere but a directive? All I can think of is putting the `ng-controller` on the body tag, together with a `ng-title` directive, and let that directive search upward until it finds the parent doc's `head` tag.

Comment: Also, how would you utilize `ng-href` on `<link>` to dynamically include stylesheets then?

Answer (score 13):

I don't think there will be any problem so far.
The only impact is the rootscope no more readable from html markup, because the controller scope is overriding it.

For example,

```
<div id="parent" ng-app>
  <div id="child" ng-controller='...'>

$rootScope.$id = 002    // rootscope from $rootscope service
$("#parent").scope().$id =002 // rootscope scope get from element scope    
$("#child").scope().$id =003  // controller scope get from element scope
```

when it comes to the same markup,

```
<div id="parent" ng-app ng-controller='...'>

$rootScope.$id = 002    // rootscope from $rootscope service
$("#parent").scope().$id =003 // controller scope get from element scope
```

Here you have no way to get rootscope from element scope, but who cares.

Comment: you can reach the parent usually through ng-init or by another object such as $rootScope.object.$id