# Application' main controller' scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Just to understand little more a scopes inheritance , after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254400/is-it-bad-to-declare-ng-app-and-ng-controller-on-html-tag) i have a question. Why when we're declaring an `ng-app` and `ng-controller` on a same tag , this controller's scope is not equal to the `rootScope`?

```
 <html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl"></html>

 app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function( $scope , $rootScope ) {

    console.log( angular.equals ( $scope , $rootScope ) ); // false

 });
```

Testing: http://plnkr.co/edit/7mAFeZ?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every controller defines its own nested scope of which `$rootScope` is the (ultimate) ancestor.  If you're a bit more curious, checkout the definition of the `ngController` directive.  It sets a new scope (`scope: true`) and sets itself as the controller.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngController.js#L164

Answer (score 1):

Angular will always create its own $rootScope regardless of your controller declarations.

The scope from your ng-controller will inherit from the $rootScope as though you called $rootScope.$new()

Comment: Thanks , KevinStone' link actually explains this issue ,`ngController` has `scope: true`