# AngularJS ng-controller in html root element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-controller

I have an AngularJS document where I need to set fields in various parts of the document. This includes e.x. the `<title>` tag. So my document Looks like the following:

```
<html ng-app="test" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <head>
        <title>{{test1}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{test1}}</h1>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I put the ng-controller in the `<html>` tag because I need to use the same scope across `<head>` and `<body>`. I could also set the controller on the individual elements but since I'm doing some POST and GET queries I think it's not a good idea because then they are performed multiple times.

Is using the `ng-controller` tag in the `<html>` element a good idea (is there a negative impact)? Are there better solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it bad to declare ng-app and ng-controller on html tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254400/is-it-bad-to-declare-ng-app-and-ng-controller-on-html-tag)

Comment: you can use highest vote answer of this post also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506329/how-to-dynamically-change-header-based-on-angularjs-partial-view